# What's the purpose for Spring AMQP listener transactions

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm trying to understand how transaction works in Spring AMQP. Reading the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#transactions , I know the purpose for enabling transaction in publisher (Best Effort One Phase Commit pattern) but I have no idea why it could be necessary in MessageListener?

Let's take an example:

`acknowledgeMode=AUTO`

1. Consume message using `@RabbitListener`
2. Insert data into database
3. Publish message using `rabbitTemplate`

According to docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#acknowledgeMode, if `acknowledgeMode` is set to `AUTO` then if any next operation fails, listener will fail too and message will be returned to queue.

Another question is whats the difference between local transaction and external transaction in that case (setting `container.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());` or not)?

I would appreciate some clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

Enable transactions in the listener so that any/all downstream `RabbitTemplate` operations participate in the same transaction.

If there is a failure, the container will rollback the transaction (removing the publishes), nack the message (or messages if batch size is greater than one) and then commit the nacks so the message(s) will be redelivered.

When using an external transaction manager (such as JDBC), the container will synchronize the AMQP transaction with the external transaction.

Downstream templates participate in the transaction regardless of whether it is local (AMQP only) or synchronized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gary. So only purpose I can see is to not commit publishes if something goes wrong with listener ack. Still, it does not make any sense for me if I need to deal with "at least once delivery" at the end.

Comment: It's not just if something goes wrong with the listener ack; if the container does not start the transaction, each `RabbitTemplate` operation will either run in its own transaction, or a global transaction, and commit. Let's say the listener calls a method than is annotated `@Transactional` (with DB updates and/or Rabbit publishes) that method commits normally, but something else goes wrong in the listener before returning. The transaction won't be rolled back but the message(s) will be redelivered. This is avoided by the container controlling the scope of the transaction.

Comment: That's clear but what's the point to avoiding that situation. In case which you provided we cannot "undo" db commit anyway. Can we? The only side effect is that the message will be consumed again. And it shouldn't be a big deal if code is idempotent.

Comment: If the container starts the transaction (external) both transactions won't commit unless the listener exits normally. If the `@Transactional` method is propagation `REQUIRED` it will just use the transaction that the container started.

Comment: Exactly the behaviour I was looking for! Thanks @GaryRussell